# How to customize height of alert box using sweetalert in angular?

Tags: angular, sweetalert

I am using SweetAlert for displaying alert box in my angular application. Everything works fine but I am not able to set height for alert box. There is option for setting width of alert box but there is nothing for height. I have used code in function like below:

```
 showSuccessAlert() {
    Swal.fire({
      position: 'bottom-right',
      icon: 'success',
      title: 'Success!!!',
      showConfirmButton: true,
      width: '400px'
    });
  }
```

How to set height of alert box as per my need ?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply custom classes to different parts of the alert, the different parts from the `SweetAlertOptions` are:

```
* Swal.fire({
*   customClass: {
*     container: '...',
*     popup: '...',
*     title: '...',
*     closeButton: '...',
*     icon: '...',
*     image: '...',
*     input: '...',
*     inputLabel: '...',
*     validationMessage: '...',
*     actions: '...',
*     confirmButton: '...',
*     denyButton: '...',
*     cancelButton: '...',
*     loader: '...',
*     footer: '...'
*   }
* })
```

So you can make a class like

```
.large-sa-popup {
  height: {YOUR_HEIGHT_HERE}px
}
```

and just apply that to the the popup like:

```
showSuccessAlert() {
  Swal.fire({
    position: 'bottom-right',
    icon: 'success',
    title: 'Success!!!',
    showConfirmButton: true,
    width: '400px',
    customClass: {
      popup: 'large-sa-popup'
    }
  });
}
```

and that should apply the new height (and any other CSS properties you may want to apply).